# Remove zero elements with same index from two arrays

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

Given two `numpy` arrays with the same length, I need to remove from both of them those same index elements that are zero. For example, given the arrays

```
a = [5 9 2 0 1 4 9 0 8 1]
b = [1 0 3 1 2 4 2 0 3 2]
```

I'd need to obtain

```
a = [5 9 2 0 1 4 9 8 1]
b = [1 0 3 1 2 4 2 3 2]
```

i.e., only the element that had a zero value *in both arrays* was removed *from both arrays*. I've tried this approach

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
b = np.random.randint(0, 10, 10)

a_z_idx = [a != 0]
b_z_idx = [b != 0]

ab_z_idx = a_z_idx and b_z_idx

a = a[ab_z_idx]
b = b[ab_z_idx]
```

but this also removes those elements that are zero in either array, instead of just removing elements that are zero in of both of them.

My actual arrays have several millions of elements, so I'm after the most efficient method possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a combined mask and index -

```
mask = ~((a == 0) & (b==0))
a,b = a[mask], b[mask]
```

Alternative way to create the mask -

```
mask = (a!=0) | (b!=0)
```

If you fancy built-ins, those would translate to -

```
~np.logical_and( a==0, b==0)
np.logical_or( a!=0, b!=0)
```

Runtime test comparing the mask creation codes -

```
In [342]: a = np.random.randint(0,10,(100000))

In [343]: b = np.random.randint(0,10,(100000))

In [344]: %timeit ~((a == 0) & (b==0))
     ...: %timeit (a!=0) | (b!=0)
     ...: %timeit ~np.logical_and( a==0, b==0)
     ...: %timeit np.logical_or( a!=0, b!=0)
     ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 67.7 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 62.8 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 68.4 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 62.8 µs per loop
```

Not seeing any clear winner. If you are to be picky, get one of those `OR-ing` based ones .

Comment: Great answer Divakar! Do you know if any of those methods is noticeably faster than the other?